# Can I add a set of words to the Vim autocomplete vocabulary?

Tags: vim, autocomplete

In Vim, I'm aware of using CTRL-n and CTRL-p to autocomplete words found in the document. This is great for promoting the use of descriptive method and variable names.

I would like to add a set of words to autocomplete that I often but are not in the source file I'm currently editing. My current solution is to just add the list of words to a comment at the bottom of my template file, but that seems a bit wasteful and kludgey at best.

Is there a way to add words to Vim's autocomplete vocabulary that would be accessible to every Vim session?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use abbreviations in your `~/.vimrc` file for just a couple of words:

```
:abbr supe superuser
:abbr autoc autocomplete
:abbr que question
```

These will auto-complete after pressing <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>. So if you typed `que` then pressed <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> it would finish the word "question" for you.

If you are adding a lot and want this interface:

[image]

You can use [dictionaries](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27dictionary%27). Simply set up a file with a word on each line, then in your .vimrc add a line like this:

```
set dictionary+=/home/john/dict.txt
```

Replace the path with your dictionary file's location. You can then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> to bring up the suggestions. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> to select the next/previous out of multiple selections.

Comment: This worked! I don't get that nice looking menu though. I'm using VIM 6.3.82, which is not the latest version.

Comment: Ah... does updating help? You need to press the sequence Ctrl-x, Ctrl-k to bring up the menu. Glad to help though :)

Comment: Just checked that this works in VIM 7.2. Thanks again!

Answer (score 6):

The "sources" to the regular autocomplete (the one you get from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>) are taken from the `complete` option (see `:h 'complete'`) The default is

```
complete=.,w,b,u,t
```

which means

1. `.` scan the current buffer
2. `w` scan buffers from other windows
3. `b` scan other loaded buffers that are in the buffer list
4. `u` scan the unloaded buffers that are in the buffer list
5. `t` tag completion

you can add your own dictionary with

```
set complete+=k~/.vim/keywords.txt
```

and add the keywords one per line in `~/.vim/keywords.txt`. This way you can access the completions directly with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> (there's no need to explicity invoke dictionary completion with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>). I found this to be specially useful for code completions where I have all the common used function names in `keywords.txt`